# Помогите дописать код таймера на JavaScript

Tags: аудио, таймер

Есть код таймера:

Необходимо подключить к таймеру файлы mp3.
Чтобы при отсчете Preparation, Activity и Rest играла разная музыка.
Как это лучше сделать?

```
<div class='main-container'> 

  <div class='range-container'>
    <div class='row-container'>
      <span class='text preparation'>Preparation:</span> 
      <input class='range preparation' type="range"> 
      <span class='value preparation'></span>
    </div> 
    <div class='row-container'>
      <span class='text activity'>Activity:</span> 
      <input class='range activity' type="range"> 
      <span class='value activity'></span>
    </div>  
    <div class='row-container'>
      <span class='text rest'>Rest:</span> 
      <input class='range rest' type="range"> 
      <span class='value rest'></span>
    </div>
    <div class='row-container'>
      <span class='text rounds'>Rounds:</span> 
      <input class='range rounds' type="range"> 
      <span class='value rounds'></span>
    </div>
  </div> 

  <div class='buttons-container'>
    <div class='left-container'>
      <div class='preset-button'>1</div>
      <div class='preset-button'>2</div>
    </div> 
    <div class='center-container'>
      <div class='timer'></div>
      <div class='current'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='right-container'>
      <div class='preset-button'>3</div>
      <div class='preset-button'>4</div>
    </div>
  </div> 

</div>


body {
  margin : 0;
  padding : 0;
  background-color : hsla(0, 0%, 80%, 1);
}
    .main-container {
      display : flex;
      flex-direction : column;
      justify-content : space-around;
      align-items : center;
      width : 96vw;
      height : 96vh;
      margin : 1.5vh auto;
      border : 0.5vmin solid black;
      border-radius : 2vmin;
      box-shadow : 0 0 5vmax;
      background-color : hsla(0, 0%, 60%, 1);
    }
        .range-container {
          display : flex;
          flex-direction : column;
          justify-content : space-around;
          align-items : center;
          width : 100%;
          height : 60%;
        }
            .row-container {
              display : flex;
              flex-direction : row;
              justify-content : center;
              align-items : center;
              width : 100%;
              height : 25%;
            }
                span.text {
                  width : 30%;
                  margin : 0 auto;
                  font : 4vmin monospace;
                }
                input.range {
                  width : 50%;
                  height : 100%;
                  margin : 0 auto;
                  cursor : pointer;
                }
                span.value {
                  width : 10%;
                  margin : 0 auto;
                  font : 4vmin monospace;
                }

        .buttons-container {
          display : flex;
          flex-direction : row;
          justify-content : space-around;
          align-items : center;
          width : 100%;
          height : 40%;
        }
            .left-container, .right-container {
              display : flex;
              flex-direction : column;
              justify-content : space-between;
              align-items : center;
              width : 20%;
              height : 80%;
            }
                .preset-button {
                  display : flex;
                  flex-direction : column;
                  justify-content : space-around;
                  align-items : center;
                  width : 80%;
                  height : 30%;
                  cursor : pointer;
                  margin : 10% auto;
                  border : 0.5vmin solid black; 
                  border-radius : 2vmin;
                  font : 8vmin monospace;
                  transition : 150ms;
                }
                    .preset-button:hover {
                      box-shadow : 0 0 1vmin;
                    }
                    .preset-button:active {
                      box-shadow : 0 0 1vmin;
                      transform : scale(1.05);
                    }
            .center-container {
              display : flex;
              flex-direction : column;
              justify-content : space-between;
              align-items : center;
              width : 50%;
              height : 90%;
            }
                .timer {
                  display : flex;
                  flex-direction : row;
                  justify-content : center;
                  align-items : center;
                  text-align : center;
                  width : 80%;
                  height : 60%;
                  margin : 5% auto;
                  border : 1vmin solid black; 
                  border-radius : 2vmin;
                  cursor : pointer;
                  font : 8vmin monospace;
                  transition : 150ms;
                }
                    .timer:hover {
                      box-shadow : 0 0 1vmin;
                    }
                    .timer:active {
                      box-shadow : 0 0 1vmin;
                      transform : scale(1.05);
                    }

                .current {
                  display : flex;
                  flex-direction : row;
                  justify-content : center;
                  align-items : center;
                  width : 80%;
                  height : 20%;
                  margin : 0 auto 5% auto;
                  border : 0.5vmin solid black; 
                  border-radius : 2vmin;
                  font : 8vmin monospace;
                }


@media all and (orientation : landscape) {
  .main-container {
    flex-direction : row;
  }
    .range-container {
      width : 60%;
      height : 80%;
    }
    .buttons-container {  
      width : 40%;
      height : 80%;
    }

}


var preparationInput = document.querySelector('input.range.preparation'),
    activityInput = document.querySelector('input.range.activity'),
    restInput = document.querySelector('input.range.rest'),
    roundsInput = document.querySelector('input.range.rounds')
;

var preparationSpan = document.querySelector('span.value.preparation'),
    activitySpan = document.querySelector('span.value.activity'),
    restSpan = document.querySelector('span.value.rest'),
    roundsSpan = document.querySelector('span.value.rounds')
;

var timerArea = document.querySelector('.timer'),
    currentArea = document.querySelector('.current');

var isRunning;
var interval;

initValues();

initEvents();


///////////////////////////////////////////////////
function initValues() {
  isRunning = false;

  preparationInput.min = 1;
  activityInput.min = 1;
  restInput.min = 1;
  roundsInput.min = 1;

  preparationInput.max = 10;
  activityInput.max = 60;
  restInput.max = 60;
  roundsInput.max = 20;

  preparationInput.value = 5;
  activityInput.value = 20;
  restInput.value = 10;
  roundsInput.value = 8;

  preparationSpan.innerHTML = preparationInput.value;
  activitySpan.innerHTML = activityInput.value;
  restSpan.innerHTML = restInput.value;
  roundsSpan.innerHTML = roundsInput.value;

  timerArea.innerHTML = "START";
  currentArea.innerHTML = '0 / 0';
}


function initEvents() {
  preparationInput.oninput = function() {
    preparationSpan.innerHTML = preparationInput.value;
  };

  activityInput.oninput = function() {
    activitySpan.innerHTML = activityInput.value;
  };

  restInput.oninput = function() {
    restSpan.innerHTML = restInput.value;
  };

  roundsInput.oninput = function() {
    roundsSpan.innerHTML = roundsInput.value;
  };

  timerArea.onclick = function() {
    if(!isRunning) {
      isRunning = true;
      runTabata(preparationInput.value, activityInput.value, restInput.value, roundsInput.value);
    } else {
      isRunning = false;
      clearInterval(interval);
      timerArea.innerHTML = 'CLICK TO START NEW';
    }
  };
}


function runTabata(preparation, activity, rest, rounds) {
  var arrPeriods = [preparation],
      index = 0
  ;

  for(var i = 0; i < rounds; i++) {
    arrPeriods.push(activity);
    arrPeriods.push(rest);
  }

  runTimer(arrPeriods, index);
}


function runTimer(arrPeriods, index) {
  var timeNow, timeFuture, timeDifference;

  timeFuture = new Date();
  timeFuture = timeFuture.getTime();
  timeFuture = timeFuture + arrPeriods[index] * 1000;

  interval = setInterval(function() {
    timeNow = new Date();
    timeDifference = Math.round((timeFuture - timeNow) / 1000) + 1;

    timerArea.innerHTML = timeDifference;
    currentArea.innerHTML = Math.floor(((index + 1) / 2)) + " / " + (arrPeriods.length - 1) / 2;

    if(timeDifference === 1) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      if(index < arrPeriods.length-1) {
        index++;
        runTimer(arrPeriods, index);
      } else {
        initValues();
      }
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам! Я просто создал новую функцию для проигрывания музыки, а в код цикла добавил счетчик и в функции проверял условия по счетчику, при которых проигрывать музыку.